# Ansible AWS Certificate upload - MalformedCertificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, amazon-iam

I'm trying to upload a certificate to S3.

```
- name: create_elb_cert - upload certificate to aws for {{ customer_name }}
  iam_cert:
    name: '{{ elb_dns_name }}'
    state: present
    cert: '{{ some_folder}}/{{ app_cert }}_internal.pem'
    key: '{{ some_folder}}/{{ app_cert }}_internal.key'
  delegate_to: localhost
  run_once: True
  register: 'cert_details'
```

and I'm getting the following response

```
    <Code>MalformedCertificate</Code>\n    
<Message>Unable to parse certificate. Please ensure the certificate is in PEM format.</Message>
```

both *.pem and *.key files are valid and not corrupted. 
I am able to upload the certificates manually (via aws-cli)

I've also tried adding the `validate_certs: no` but it didn't help.

the Ansible machine is on a AWS EC2 Instance so I don't expect any networking issues

any idea what am i missing out on?

**EDIT:**

the workaround for this issue is to add `retries` to the ansible task.

on the 3rd/4th time is does manage to upload the certificate

[image]